# How to attach old style stacking wire in-basket brackets

Tags: wire, brackets

Old style stacking wire in-baskets have a heavy wire that is used for the stacking feature. How are the other ends of the wire attached to the next basket in the stack?

[image: One in-basket with four wires]

[image: Close up of one of the four connectors]

Comment: They appear to be bent around the main frame wire.

Comment: Are you asking how the individual wires are attached to each other where they cross? If so, are you certain that they are deliberately joined and don't just happen to get  stuck together by some finishing process (galvanizing maybe)?

Answer (score 1):

The wire has a bend on the end of it, it appears that you would just hook that bend over the wire on the bottom of the basket it will be hanging on.

Comment: This is correct.  The same type of baskets are made and sold today and do this.  See [here](https://www.homedepot.com/p/ClosetMaid-9-3-4-in-D-x-7-7-8-in-H-x-17-in-L-Hanging-Basket-for-Wire-Shelving-6222/100519850) for example.